# jQuery navigation control

Tags: jquery, html, menu, navigation

i want to show and hide the content of my website with jquery. if i click at a link at the navigation, the content should show the `<section>` with a special id.
here my code:

The navigation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("section#home").css({"display":"none"});
    $("section#order").css({"display":"none"});
    $("section#projects").css({"display":"none"});
    $("section#contact").css({"display":"none"});
    $("section#about").css({"display":"none"});

    if ($(this[href="home"])){
        $("section#home").css({"display":"block"});
    } else if ($(this[href="order"])){
        $("section#order").css({"display":"block"});
    } else if ($(this[href="projects"])){
        $("section#projects").css({"display":"block"});
    } else if ($(this[href="contact"])){
        $("section#contact").css({"display":"block"});
    } else if ($(this[href="about"])){
        $("section#about").css({"display":"block"});
    }
  });
});
```

The html-file:

```
<section id="content">
                <section id="home">
                    <h1>home</h1>
                </section>
                <section id="order">
                    <h1>order</h1>
                </section>
                <section id="projects">
                    <h1>projects</h1>
                </section>
                <section id="contact">
                    <h1>contact</h1>
                </section>
                <section id="about">
                    <h1>about</h1>
                </section>
</section>
```

It shows at every navigation-link the same page (home). What is  wrong?
you can look by your self at [Homepage](http://nitram0598.zapto.org)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax in the if condition is wrong, it should be `$(this).is('[href="home"]')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //hide all sections under #content
        $('#content > section').hide();

        //show the elemet with the given href as the id
        $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).show();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to `hide` all the `children` section inside the section with id `content`. Then just get the `href` attribute from the clicked anchor tag. And show the `section` which is having the id as same as the clicked anchor tag.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();       
    $('#content').children('section').hide();    
    $('#' + $(this).attr('href')).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: dont work..look at link, your code is uploaded, but...dont work ;(

Comment: @Tekkzz remove the concatenated # from the selector. See my updated Code.

Comment: what does `e.preventDefault()` do?

Comment: @Tekkzz You just changed your markup by removing that `#` in the href. Now your page will be reloaded when you click on it. So in order to prevent it you should use `e.preventDefault()`. Technically it will prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: ahh, thnak you for this info